# How can I use the C system call mkdir to create a hidden folder?

Tags: c, posix, mkdir

Say I want to create a folder myFolder, and I want it to be hidden. I'm having trouble finding the answer to this for Unix.

Comment: Use a name that starts with a period?

Comment: In UNIX, _all_ hidden files and folders are named with a single leading period. Try e.g. `ls -a` in your home folder to see all the hidden files and folders there.

Comment: Well, they are not exactly hidden. It's just that file browsers don't display files starting with `.` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden directory must begin with '.' dot infront of their filename.
mkdir .hidden

Comment: `mkdir .hidden` doesn't look like C to me

Comment: The question originally said 'C command', which might mean the `mkdir .hidden` command is OK since it is undoubtedly written in C.  As revised, it would be a system call: `mkdir(".hidden", 0755);`

Answer (score 4):

See [man 2 mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) for creating a folder in C. To make it hidden you must prefix the name with a dot. It's just a one-liner:

```
mkdir(".myFolder", 0755);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir .myFolde
```

Directories beginning with a dot are hidden directories in unix

Comment: `mkdir .myFolde` doesn't look like C to me

Comment: The question originally said 'C command', which might mean the `mkdir .hidden` command is OK since it is undoubtedly written in C. As revised, it would be a system call: `mkdir(".hidden", 0755);`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directory and deny read/execute access on it. Then all the files within that directory will be "hidden". `mkdir ("no-peeking-here", S_IRWXU); mkdir ("no-peeking-here/look-ma-no-dots", S_IRWXU);`
Or if you just want to reduce clutter, use the leading dot as many people suggested.